# How to use tinymix to send file playback over a phone call

Tags: android, audio, routes, call, playback

I have an S21+ android phone. During a phone call, i want instead of microphone audio to send an audio file as voice to the call party. I am trying to achieve this using tinymix to try and reroute audio.
Does anyone know how to do this? or know any alternative way to do this?

I have tried setting several values via tinymix but no luck so far.